# POCO - can I use SocketReactor as a client?

Tags: c++, tcp, poco-libraries, reactor

I see a lot of examples of SocketReactor being used in conjunction with SocketAcceptor, when people are running a TCP server.

However, i'm wanting to connect to an existing TCP server as a client, but would like to be able to handle the events exposed by SocketReactor, such as onSocketReadable, onSocketWritable, onSocketShutdown, onSocketError, and onSocketTimeout.

Is this possible with POCO libraries? I put together the following code but none of the events are triggered.
If this approach doesn't work, any other suggestions?
Basically I will be receiving a realtime stream of tcp messages from the server, and I will also send messages back to the server to perform certain tasks.

```
class ITCHProvider
    {
    private:
        Poco::Net::SocketAddress _sa;
        Poco::Net::StreamSocket _sock;
        Poco::Net::SocketStream _stream;
        Poco::Net::SocketReactor _reactor;

    public:
        ITCHProvider() :
            _sa("host", 1234),
            _sock(),
            _stream(_sock),
            _reactor()
        {
            _reactor.addEventHandler(_sock, Poco::NObserver<ITCHProvider, Poco::Net::ReadableNotification>(*this, &ITCHProvider::onSocketReadable));
            _reactor.addEventHandler(_sock, Poco::NObserver<ITCHProvider, Poco::Net::WritableNotification>(*this, &ITCHProvider::onSocketWritable));
            _reactor.addEventHandler(_sock, Poco::NObserver<ITCHProvider, Poco::Net::ShutdownNotification>(*this, &ITCHProvider::onSocketShutdown));
            _reactor.addEventHandler(_sock, Poco::NObserver<ITCHProvider, Poco::Net::ErrorNotification>(*this, &ITCHProvider::onSocketError));
            _reactor.addEventHandler(_sock, Poco::NObserver<ITCHProvider, Poco::Net::TimeoutNotification>(*this, &ITCHProvider::onSocketTimeout));

            _sock.connect(_sa);
        }

        ~ITCHProvider()
        {
            close();
        }

        void onSocketReadable(const Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::ReadableNotification>& pNf)
        {
            LOG(INFO) << "READable   !!";
        }
        void onSocketWritable(const Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::WritableNotification>& pNf)
        {
            LOG(INFO) << "WRITEable   !!";
        }
        void onSocketShutdown(const Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::ShutdownNotification>& pNf)
        {
            LOG(INFO) << "SHUTDOWN!!!!!!!!!!!!";
        }
        void onSocketError(const Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::ErrorNotification>& pNf)
        {
            LOG(INFO) << "Error!!";
        }
        void onSocketTimeout(const Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::TimeoutNotification>& pNf)
        {
            LOG(INFO) << "Timeout!!";
        }

        // Close down the connection properly.
        void close() {
            try {
                _sock.shutdown();
            }
            catch (...) {
                LOG(INFO) << "closing failed.";
            }
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done, but note that (a) nothing will happen until you actually run the reactor and (b) reactor will spin until explicitly stopped, so it is best to run it in separate thread;

here's a quick example:

```
// server-side handler
class EchoServiceHandler {
public:
    EchoServiceHandler(StreamSocket& socket, SocketReactor& reactor): _socket(socket), _reactor(reactor) {
        _reactor.addEventHandler(_socket, Observer<EchoServiceHandler, ReadableNotification>(*this, &EchoServiceHandler::onReadable));
    }

    ~EchoServiceHandler() {
        _reactor.removeEventHandler(_socket, Observer<EchoServiceHandler, ReadableNotification>(*this, &EchoServiceHandler::onReadable));
    }

    void onReadable(ReadableNotification* pNf) {
        pNf->release();
        char buffer[8];
        int n = _socket.receiveBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (n > 0) {
            _socket.sendBytes(buffer, n);
        }
        else {
            _socket.shutdownSend();
            delete this;
        }
    }

    private:
        StreamSocket   _socket;
        SocketReactor& _reactor;
};
```

your original code, slightly modified:

```
class ITCHProvider : public Poco::Runnable
{
private:
    Poco::Net::StreamSocket _sock;
    Poco::Net::SocketReactor _reactor;

public:
    ITCHProvider(const SocketAddress& sa) : _sock(sa) {
        _reactor.addEventHandler(_sock, Poco::NObserver<ITCHProvider, Poco::Net::ReadableNotification>(*this, &ITCHProvider::onSocketReadable));
        _reactor.addEventHandler(_sock, Poco::NObserver<ITCHProvider, Poco::Net::WritableNotification>(*this, &ITCHProvider::onSocketWritable));
        _reactor.addEventHandler(_sock, Poco::NObserver<ITCHProvider, Poco::Net::ShutdownNotification>(*this, &ITCHProvider::onSocketShutdown));
        _reactor.addEventHandler(_sock, Poco::NObserver<ITCHProvider, Poco::Net::ErrorNotification>(*this, &ITCHProvider::onSocketError));
        _reactor.addEventHandler(_sock, Poco::NObserver<ITCHProvider, Poco::Net::TimeoutNotification>(*this, &ITCHProvider::onSocketTimeout));
        std::string data = "Hello reactor world!";
        _sock.sendBytes(data.data(), (int)data.length());
    }

    ~ITCHProvider() { close(); }

    void run() { _reactor.run(); }
    void stop() { _reactor.stop(); }

    void onSocketReadable(const Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::ReadableNotification>& pNf) {
        std::cout << "READable   !!" << std::endl;
        char data[1025] = { 0 };
        if (_sock.receiveBytes(data, 1024) > 0) {
            std::cout << data << std::endl;
        }
    }
    void onSocketWritable(const Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::WritableNotification>& pNf) {
        std::cout << "WRITEable   !!" << std::endl;
    }
    void onSocketShutdown(const Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::ShutdownNotification>& pNf) {
        std::cout << "SHUTDOWN!!!!!!!!!!!!" << std::endl;
    }
    void onSocketError(const Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::ErrorNotification>& pNf) {
        std::cout << "Error!!" << std::endl;
    }
    void onSocketTimeout(const Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::Net::TimeoutNotification>& pNf) {
        std::cout << "Timeout!!" << std::endl;
    }

    void close() {
        try {
            _sock.shutdown();
        }
        catch (...) {
            std::cout << "closing failed." << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

now, let's run the above:

```
SocketAddress ssa;
ServerSocket ss(ssa);
SocketReactor reactor;
SocketAcceptor<EchoServiceHandler> acceptor(ss, reactor);
Thread server;
server.start(reactor);
ITCHProvider provider(SocketAddress("127.0.0.1", ss.address().port()));
Thread client;
client.start(provider);
Thread::sleep(1000);
reactor.stop();
provider.stop();
server.join();
client.join();
```

output (writable and timeout notifications silenced for clarity):

```
READable   !!
Hello reactor world!
SHUTDOWN!!!!!!!!!!!!
```